# TP4056 STDBY or CHARGE COMPLETED PIN PROBLEM

Tags: battery-charging, charger, charge, tp4056

I have charger circuit TP4056 based. My battery capacitY is 1100mAh(LIPO). Charging current is 580mA according to datasheet that has R9.

While I am charging the battery, i read 0V from BAT_CHG pin. There is no problem.

I charge the battery for 4-5 hours. But BAT_CMPLT pin never triggered. While battery is charging,BAT_CHG pin always is triggered.

But; After 2 hours, when I remove the charging cable and plug it back in, the BAT_CMPLT pin is triggered.

Help me please :)

[image]

Comment: Anything else connected to the battery?

Comment: @Finbarr Yes. While the battery is charging, i turn on led group. led group draws about 150mA. Because of that ? is there a way to do this? how can i calculate?

Comment: Well, there's your problem. The TP4056 thinks the LED current is going into the battery so it thinks the charging is still in progress. The danger is that it will never stop, the battery will get overcharged and potentially destroyed. Maybe even catch fire or explode. Power the LEDs directly from the 5V supply instead of from the TP4056.